# I don't know what's wrong with my ajax function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to use Ajax. The only thing that I succeeded learning is the load function. Now I'm try to use `$.ajax({})`. Now here's my attempt using this function:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ajax test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#send").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"show.php",
                        method: "post",
                        data :{value: <?php echo $value;?>},
                        success:function(data){
                            $("#showVal").html(data);
                            alert("succes");
                        }
                    });
               });     
               }); 

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="showVal" ></p>
        <form id="test" name="tst">
            <?php 
                $value = 15;
            ?>
            <button type="button" id="send">Press me!</button>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the show.php file is:

```
<?php
    $val=$_POST['value'];
    echo 'Your value '.$val.' . Have a nice day!';?>
```

If you know what could be the problem share with me ! Thanks ! Have a great day guys!

Comment: so what is happening when u try to send?

Comment: Looks like you define `$value` **after** you try to echo it

Comment: @pc_coder well, I don't get any text from show.php. Even if values was null in data, i would get some text. But now, I don't get anything. Also the files are in the same folder. I don't know what could be.

Comment: have you checked the browser console? I'm expecting to see a syntax error, for the reason that @charlietfl mentions (since PHP `null` values echo as blank)

Comment: @charlietfl i move the $value before and nothing's happening. Still same result.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm getting this error in browser console: *Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' * in line with data initialization and i can't figure out why.